# sql show 0 when no records where found

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show a zero when no records where found for that particular id.
[image]

The image is the representation of what I'm trying to achieve. Right now I'm only getting the rows where he finds at least one record (so 3, 4 and 5).

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here's my attempt (one of many):

### EDIT:

```
SELECT  statusses.statusses_namenl,
        IFNULL(COUNT(projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid),0) AS CntRows
FROM recipes
RIGHT JOIN projectrecipes
ON projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_recipeid = recipes.id
LEFT JOIN statusses
ON recipes.fk_recipe_status = statusses.id
WHERE projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213
GROUP BY recipes.fk_recipe_status
```

### EDIT:

This is the result I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a row per status, so select from statusses. Then you want to count records from recipes and projectrecipes per status, so outer join them. Put your criteria in the ON clause, not in the WHERE clause, because when there is no matching record, fk_projectrecipes_projectid will be NULL. (You turn the outer join into an inner join by using an outer joined column in the where clause.)

```
select s.statusses_namenl, count(*)
from statusses
left join recipes r on r.fk_recipe_status = s.id
left join projectrecipes pr on pr.fk_projectrecipes_recipeid = r.id and pr.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213
group by s.statusses_namenl;
```

Comment: If I use this query. I'm getting all records in projectrecipes (id 1 500, id 2 1234, ...). But whilst typing this comment I found the solution. I replaced count * with the cound I had and now I've got the answer.
Thanks a lot! you saved my day.

Comment: Ah yes, stupid me. Of course you are getting recipes that are not in project 213. Sorry. I'm glad, you found the solution in spite of my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to use the CASE, and also use RIGHT join so if no match comes in Join then also the result will come. Try below it should work.

```
SELECT  recipes.fk_recipe_status, COUNT(projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid)
FROM projectrecipes
RIGHT JOIN recipes
ON projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_recipeid = recipes.id
WHERE projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213
GROUP BY recipes.fk_recipe_status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  recipes.fk_recipe_status, 
        IFNULL(COUNT(projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid),0) AS CntRows
FROM projectrecipes
RIGHT JOIN recipes
ON projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_recipeid = recipes.id
WHERE projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213
GROUP BY recipes.fk_recipe_status
```

Comment: He is using recipes.fk_recipe_status. If you do a left join this will be null for the non found records. isnt it? Let me know if missing anything?

Comment: Tried both (left and right join). Both returned the same as what I had (only id's 3, 4 and 5)

Comment: @NathalieDeHertogh: Can you show some sample data in the tables. It could be so helpful to find the correct query.

Comment: @NathalieDeHertogh: Can you create a template in [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20ec3/12)

Comment: What do you mean by template?

Comment: @NathalieDeHertogh: Go to the link I have provided (or www.sqlfiddle.com), click 'Text to DDL' and provide some data and build table. then give me the link to that template. It will be more easier to test in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  recipes.fk_recipe_status,
        COALESCE(COUNT(projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid),0) AS CntRows
FROM projectrecipes
RIGHT JOIN recipes
ON projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_recipeid = recipes.id
WHERE projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213
GROUP BY recipes.fk_recipe_status
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the join and where should be changed, too. So I take A Paul answers and modify:

```
SELECT  recipes.fk_recipe_status, COUNT(projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid)
```

Turn the tables in JOIN

```
FROM recipes
LEFT JOIN projectrecipes
ON projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_recipeid = recipes.id

GROUP BY recipes.fk_recipe_status
```

add a having instead of where

```
HAVING projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213
   OR COUNT(projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid) = 0
```

For some recipes (1 and 2 in example) no data in projectrecipes could be found. So if you select from projectrecipes first, you won't get all data from recipes.

As projectrecipes may not contain data in result, projectrecipes.fk_projectrecipes_projectid = 213 will always be false. If no data is found, check for no data found e.g. count = 0.